# Releasing an object but still able to use it

Tags: iphone, ios, release-management

I had understood that once you release an object, you shouldn't use it as it will cause an error since it is not in memory anymore.

But reading thru [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOM.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005190-SW4) Apple guide, I found this code, and have also seen it before, but I would just move the `[object release]` to the end of my code, so as to avoid getting an error.  But it seems that it is accepted and works. So, why does this work? How can it keep setting variables to `dateAttribute` after it's been released?

(Line 3 is the one in question):

```
NSMutableArray *runProperties = [NSMutableArray array];

NSAttributeDescription *dateAttribute = [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
[runProperties addObject:dateAttribute];
[dateAttribute release];
[dateAttribute setName:@"date"];
[dateAttribute setAttributeType:NSDateAttributeType];
[dateAttribute setOptional:NO];
```

Got it from here: [Creating a managed object model in code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOM.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005190-SW4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few points we should discuss.

1. `release` does *not* always make the object deallocated. The object will be deallocated only at the "last" release, i.e. when the retain count drop to zero.
2. Despite of that, it is still hold true that you should not use the object after you release it, because it is *possible* that it might be deallocated already.
3. The `NSMutableArray` will retain the object until it is removed from the array, or the array itself be allocated.

The example take the advantage that the array will `retain` the reference when added, so the reference will not be deallocated yet after releasing `dateAttribute`. However, this is not a good style because its validity depends solely on the nature of the class `NSMutableArray` itself, and it breaks common rule that we should not use released reference.

Comment: Edited to remove reference to `retainCount`. The concept of dropping to 0 is valid, but `retainCount` can never actually return 0 for obvious reasons.

Comment: Does the compiler change `dateAttribute` to the memory address? Because to me, even if the array makes another `retain` on the object, it is still two different pointers (one called dateAttribute, another called runProperties[0]). So, if I release `dateAttribute`, I'm thinking I'm releasing the pointer to that object, and the only way to use the object would be  `[[runProperties objectAtIndex:0] setSomething:blah];`

Comment: No, the dateAttribute will point to the same address after releasing, and no matter that the releasing causes deallocation or not.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this is bad style, however it does work.

NSMutableArray (the runProperties addObject) calls `retain` on the dateAttribute. Therefore, calling release does not destroy the dateAttribute (there is still one reference).

For readability and refactoring reasons, I would also place the call to `release` *last*.